# how to send post to remote url and redirect to the url in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, curl

I used curl before, I want to send data by POST from location A to location B, and the location  in the end is B not A. while in fact the last URL is A using curl, not what I actually want , how to solve this problem?

我之前用过curl这个方法，我希望通过POST方法把数据从地址A发送到地址B，而且最后的地址是B而不是A。但是事实上用curl的话最后的地址是A，不是我事实上期望的，怎样解决这个问题？

my code(I used CI framework )：

```
<?php
class See extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function a(){
        $url='http://localhost/Test2/index.php/see/b';
        $data=array(
            'act'=>'botton',
            'foo'=>'bar'
        );
        $ch=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $output=curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
    public function b(){
        echo $_POST['act'];
        echo '<br/>';
        echo $_POST['foo'];
    }

}
```

I want it to work like that in Java as this:

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5000); // 设置连接超时为5秒
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(httpUrl);
    HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
    request.setEntity(entity);
    if (JSESSIONID != null) {
        request.setHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + JSESSIONID);
        // System.out.println(JSESSIONID+"哈哈");
    }
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams); 
    // 取得HTTP response
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    // 如果返回状态为200，获得返回的结果
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        byte[] bytes = EntityUtils.toByteArray(response.getEntity());
        CookieStore mCookieStore = client.getCookieStore();
        List<Cookie> cookies = mCookieStore.getCookies();
        for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
            // 这里是读取Cookie['SESSIONID']的值存在静态变量中，保证每次都是同一个值
            if ("JSESSIONID".equals(cookies.get(i).getName())) {
                JSESSIONID = cookies.get(i).getValue();
                break;
            }

        }
        // System.out.println(new String(bytes,"UTF-8"));
        return bytes;
    } else
        System.out
                .println("状态码" + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    return "连接错误！".getBytes();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow completely, but if you want to POST data from A to B, and then redirect the user in their web browser to B, just send a header to the user after the POST completes, e.g. `header("Location: http://b.example.com)`.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a basic form functionality, set the action attribute of the form tag to location B - no need to use curl.

Comment: if not use curl, how to do?

Comment: It seems you want to hit a url like `localhost/Test2/index.php/see/a` and redirect to link `localhost/Test2/index.php/see/b` with some post data.You cannot do it with curl.You need to do some tric. When you enter page-a keep a form with those value and set that form action url to page-b and method post .after that add some javascript which will submit the form auto.hope you understand.

Comment: it runs on server,js is not useful

Comment: Shaiful Islam: I want post the data to third -party website,and some data is private,I don't hope that someone could see the source in the browser,so I can't use JavaScript or form. Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: Charlie S: header is Get function,not Post.And header can't transform data posted

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `stream_context_create` and `file_get_contents` for this, and send your data as an array.

```
    $url = "http://localhost/Test2/index.php/see/b";

    $data = array('act' => 'botton', 'botton' => 'bar');

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

The other end will receive it as:

```
    $act = $this->input->post('act');
    $botton = $this->input->post('botton');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,however, it doesn't works. I entered the url "http://localhost/Test2/index.php/see/a" and there is nothing display,the URL is still a

Comment: Are they different servers? What error messages do you get?